# Set Token Validation Period in Identity Server 4

Tags: identityserver4

What is the mechanism for setting a token validation period in Identity Server 4? Can the validation period vary for different tokens?

The Identity Server 4 documentation at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/ shows a AuthorizationEndpoint with a property max_age, which is what I think I want, but the documentation does not really show it it inter-operates with the quickstart code for IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Token lifetimes are set per client application. This includes both identity and access tokens. See [client application entity](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/reference/client.html#token).

If you are talking about session length this is set by each application upon successful authentication using IdentityServer.

Comment: Using the information provided by @Scott Brady I have modified the Config.cs file in IdentyServerWithAspNetIdentity project to modify the Client object configured there. See the fix in the solution below

Answer (score 4):

I have modified the Client object in Config.cs of the IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity

```
            // OpenID Connect hybrid flow and client credentials client (MVC)
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                RequireConsent = false,

                ClientSecrets = 
                {
                    new Secret("LynxJournal".Sha256())
                },

                //RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                //PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002" },
                RedirectUris = { serverConfig["MvcClientUrl"]  + "/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { serverConfig["MvcClientUrl"] },

                IdentityTokenLifetime = 3600,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                AuthorizationCodeLifetime = 3600,

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                    StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                    StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
                    "api1"
                }
            }
```

This extends the life of the token to one hour where before the defaults seemed to give about 15-20 minutes. I added values for IdentityTokenLifetime, AccessTokenLifetime and AuthorizationCodeLifetime